# Fantasy book where the dark lord kept prisoners in a giant wheel on the side of a mountain

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to remember the name of a fantasy novel from the late 90s/early 2000s.

It involved a dark lord keeping prisoners in cages on a giant prison ferris wheel on the side of a mountain.
It ended with the hero killing the dark lord by throwing a rock at his head.

I think it was the first in a series.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was the wheel vertical, like a ferris wheel, or horizontal, like a roulette wheel?  I seem to recall a story like the latter, where prisoners were trapped underground until their cell rotated back to the entrance.

Comment: @DavidW - I think that’s from one of Brian Aldiss’ Helliconia books; it was my first thought, too, but I don’t remember enough to say if it’s a match.

Comment: @andrewsi That's definitely the one I was thinking of.  Details here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/185858/101407

Comment: I think Brian Aldiss must have copied the "rotating prison" idea from Edgar Rice Burroughs - in the 2nd and 3rd of the John Carter Barsoom books he is in the forbidden Valley Dor where the fake god Therns rule. They have a rotating prison which takes a full Martian year to do a complete turn and then release you.

Comment: Hi, the wheel was definitely vertical, on the side of a mountain. The book was from the early 2000s.

Comment: Can anyone help?